# Center a html div

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I know using margin:0 auto  will center the div.
But in my case its not working.And i'm not able to figure out my issue.
If somebody could guide me in the right direction it will be very helpful.

Below is the html

I want the circle div and image tag to be in the center of the segment always.it is in center horizontally but not vertically its stays at the top of the segment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Shruti Nair:Freelancers</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top menu">
      <div class="container menu">
           <a class="navbar-brand menuButton" href="#">ABOUT</a>
           <a class="navbar-brand menuButton" href="#">SKILLS</a>
           <a class="navbar-brand menuButton" href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
           <a class="navbar-brand menuButton" href="#">EXPERIENCE</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="content-box content">

         <section style="background-color:#90ECF2;min-height:500px;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;">
          <div>

                 <div class="circletag" id="nay">
                    <img src="img/defaultAvatars.png">
                 </div>

                  <h1 class="heading">SHRUTI NAIR</h1>
                  <span>Hybrid Mobile App developer</span>
            </div>
         </section>
    </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is the css

```
.menu{
    background-color: white;

}
.menuButton{
    color: black !important;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:14px;

}
.content{
    margin-top:50px;
}

.heading{
    color:white;
}

.circletag {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #E6E7ED;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;    
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.circletag img{
    margin-top:7px;
    width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
section > div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[See the example](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielbbica/L1175mau/)

Answer (score 2):

add `display:flex` in the `section` and `margin:auto` to the child div which you want to show at the center(i.e. horizontally and vertically).

Check below snippet

```css
.menu {
  background-color: white;
}

.menuButton {
  color: black !important;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.heading {
  color: white;
}

.circletag {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #E6E7ED;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.circletag img {
  margin-top: 7px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Shruti Nair:Freelancers</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top menu">
    <div class="container menu">
      <a class="navbar-brand menuButton" href="#">ABOUT</a>
      <a class="navbar-brand menuButton" href="#">SKILLS</a>
      <a class="navbar-brand menuButton" href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
      <a class="navbar-brand menuButton" href="#">EXPERIENCE</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="content-box content">

    <section style="background-color:#90ECF2;min-height:500px;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;display:flex;">
      <div style="margin:auto">

        <div class="circletag" id="nay">
          <img src="img/defaultAvatars.png">
        </div>

        <h1 class="heading">SHRUTI NAIR</h1>
        <span>Hybrid Mobile App developer</span>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>


  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.menu{
    background-color: white;

}
.menuButton{
    color: black !important;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:14px;

}
.content{
   // margin-top:50px;
}

.heading{
    color:white;
}

.circletag {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #E6E7ED;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;    
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.circletag img{
    margin-top:7px;
    width:100px;
}

section{
  background-color:#90ECF2;min-height:500px;
  display:flex;
  display:-ms-flexbox; 
  display:-webkit-flex; 
  align-items:center;justify-content:center;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top menu">
      <div class="container menu">
           <a class="navbar-brand menuButton" href="#">ABOUT</a>
           <a class="navbar-brand menuButton" href="#">SKILLS</a>
           <a class="navbar-brand menuButton" href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
           <a class="navbar-brand menuButton" href="#">EXPERIENCE</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="content-box content">

         <section >
          <div>

                 <div class="circletag" id="nay">
                    <img src="img/defaultAvatars.png">
                 </div>

                  <h1 class="heading">SHRUTI NAIR</h1>
                  <span>Hybrid Mobile App developer</span>
            </div>
         </section>
    </div>
```

Is this the same that you are looking for?

Here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sqd9a9z1/)

Hope this helps.